# Databinding Error 40 with Sub-Properties in 4.0 WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, c#-4.0, data-binding, devexpress

I'm having difficultly troubleshooting this error I'm receiving with sub-properties of my bound object.

The output log:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : 
BindingExpression path error: 
'ModuleTitle' property not found on 'object' ''MainViewModel' (HashCode=20054924)'.
BindingExpression:Path=ModuleTitle; 
DataItem='MainViewModel' (HashCode=20054924); 
target element is 'Module' (Name=''); 
target property is 'Content' (type 'Object')

System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : 
BindingExpression path error: 
'HexColorValue' property not found on 'object' ''MainViewModel' (HashCode=20054924)'. 
BindingExpression:Path=HexColorValue; 
DataItem='MainViewModel' (HashCode=20054924); 
target element is 'Module' (Name=''); 
target property is 'Background' (type 'Brush')

System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : 
BindingExpression path error: 
'ImageSource' property not found on 'object' ''MainViewModel' (HashCode=20054924)'. 
BindingExpression:Path=ImageSource; 
DataItem='MainViewModel' (HashCode=20054924); 
target element is 'Module' (Name=''); 
target property is 'TileGlyph' (type 'ImageSource')
```

My View:

```
<UserControl definition ...>

<UserControl.DataContext>
    <ViewModels:MainViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>

...


        <dxnav:TileBar x:Name="MainNavigation_TileBar" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ItemSpacing="3" ItemsSource="{Binding NavModules}">
            <dxnav:TileBar.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="dxnav:TileBarItem">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding ModuleTitle}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="166"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding HexColorValue}"/>
                    <Setter Property="TileGlyph" Value="{Binding ImageSource}"/>
                </Style>
            </dxnav:TileBar.ItemContainerStyle>

...
```

View Model:

```
public partial class MainViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Module> NavModules { get { return Module.AvailableNavModules; } }

    public MainViewModel() 
    { 

    }
}
```

Module Class (properties are set privately in constructor):

```
public class Module : TileBarItem
{
    public string ModuleTitle { get; private set; }

    public string ImageSource { get; private set; }

    public string HexColorValue { get; private set; }

    public string ModuleGroup { get; private set; }

    public string ModuleView { get; private set; }

    public static readonly ObservableCollection<Module> AvailableNavModules = new ObservableCollection<Module>()
    {
        new Module("Search", "/Resources/Icons/Modules/Search.png", ModuleColor.AQUA, _RECORD_GROUP, "SearchPageView"),
        new Module("Record Keeping", "/Resources/Icons/Modules/RecordKeeping.png", ModuleColor.BLACK, _RECORD_GROUP, "RecordKeepingView"),
        new Module("Scheduling", "/Resources/Icons/Modules/Scheduling.png", ModuleColor.ORANGE, _SCHEDULING_GROUP, "SchedulingView"),
        new Module("Management", "/Resources/Icons/Modules/Management.png", ModuleColor.BLUE, _MANAGEMENT_GROUP, "ManagementView")
    };
```

All of the properties are set using the simple `{ get; set; }` implementation like I have done elsewhere in the project. It's just not working for this specific use. When I load the program, it properly loads the object `NavModules`, but none of the sub-properties have been set for display.

Previously, I had forgotten to add `{ get; set; }` to the `ObservableCollection<Module> NavModules`, but now I can't get it to find the sub-properties.

Suggestions?

Comment: Why is the view model class Module derived from the view class TileBarItem? That seems to be wrong. That said, are you sure the binding errors really come from the XAML you're showing? The `DataItem` in the ItemsContainerStyle should be of type `Module`, not MainViewModel.

Comment: When it did not derive from `TileBarItem` I received an error stating that `TileBar` only accepts `TileBarItem`.

I will set `ItemsContainerStyle`'s data context to `Module` and see if that works.

Comment: That sounds like you are adding items directly to the TileBar, instead of adding them to the NavModules collection. I admit that I do not know the TileBar control, but when it is a derived ItemsControl, the bound ItemsSource collection would not have to contain TileBarItem (or derived) objects.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer towards `TileBarItem` deriving. I removed it and everything worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had `Module` derive from `TileBarItem` so the path wasn't working as intended.

New class declaration:

```
public class Module
{
    public string ModuleTitle { get; private set; }
    public string ImageSource { get; private set; }

    ....
}
```